# Indentify unique users across XenApp farm with Powershell

Tags: powershell, xenapp

I hope someone can help me with this.

I'm trying to create a small powershell script that should generate a output like this:

```
Servername     Users
Server01       10
Server02       11
Server03       9
```

The command:

```
(get-xasession -farm | Select-Object Accountname | Sort AccountName | Get-    Unique -AsString).count
```

Gives me the total amount of unique users within the enviroment.

The (small) script:

```
add-pssnapin -name citrix.xenapp.* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$sessions=0
$servers=@(Get-XAServer | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -match 'Servers/2 Publishing Servers'} | Sort ServerName)
foreach ($server in $servers)
{ 
     (Get-XASession -Servername $server | Select-Object AccountName -Unique).count
}
```

Gives me a unique count per server, only it is not showing which server.

So, I'm able to get the total count, the individual count but not formatted into a table.

And yes. I'm new to this. Trying (with a lot of Google) to find my way around in Powershell. Only, now I'm stuck.

Comment: `| Get-    Unique -AsString` I'm sure this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this :

```
add-pssnapin -name citrix.xenapp.* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$sessions=0
$servers=@(Get-XAServer | Where-Object {$_.FolderPath -match 'Servers/2 Publishing Servers'} | Sort ServerName | select -ExpandProperty ServerName)
$data= @()
foreach ($server in $servers) { 
   $data += new-object -TypeName psobject -Property @{name = $server; count = (Get-XASession -Servername $server | Select-Object AccountName -Unique).count }
}
$data
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. Now for me to learn from this. Thanks again.